# Difference between @author and @group annotation in phpunit

Tags: php, annotations, phpunit

Difference between @author and @group annotation in phpunit. What's written in the documentation is that the former is an alias of the latter. Can someone please explain that further? When and how to use @author and @group?

Comment: for that you will get you must refer  https://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/appendixes.annotations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@author` to mark who has written the tests. Use `@group` to mark logically connected tests.

```
class MyText extends PHPUnitTestCase {

    /**
     * @author user2
     * @group myFeature1
     */
    public function test1() { /* ... */ }


    /**
     * @author user1
     * @group myFeature2
     */
    public function test2() { /* ... */ }

    /**
     * @author user1
     * @group myFeature1
     */
    public function test3() { /* ... */ }

}
```

Now, when you run `phpunit MyTest.php --group myFeature1`, only test1 and test3 will be run. When you use `phpunit MyTest.php --group user1`, only the test2 and test3 will be run.

It is the similar behavior that they mean by an `alias`. The only difference is the name. Both allows to specify which tests to run.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. Now, what I'm trying to explore is that is it possible for me to fetch annotation attribute(like @author value) for any test case, programatically, so that I may automatically assign the test case (should it fail) to that person or group.

Comment: You might use some annotation reader (e.g. http://goo.gl/GXn5G3). However, please note that the author of the test is not resposible for its failure in the future. It is the person who made code changes to be notified that some tests fail after his modifications.